# Elasticsearch connect with MySQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch connect with MySQL . How to create database in MySQL and search through the information with elasticsearch? Can we do the same job in php or other language?

Comment: You have to explain in a bit more details what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far. As it stands, your question might be closed because it is too broad and difficult to answer because it depends on too many unknowns about your specific environment and use case(s).

Comment: See if these questions are of any use to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152152/elasticsearch-how-to-integrate-with-mysql

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410920/elasticsearch-usage-with-mysql