# How to integrate ElasticSearch with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5, elk

In one of my project, I am planning to use ElasticSearch with MySQL.
I have successfully installed ElasticSearch. I am able to manage index in ES separately. but I don't know how to implement the same with MySQL.

I have read a couple of documents but I am a bit confused and not having a clear idea.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As of ES 5.x , they have given this feature out of the box with [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html) plugin.

This will periodically import data from database and push to ES server.

One has to create a simple import file given below (which is also described [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin)) and use logstash to run the script. Logstash supports running this script on a schedule.

```
# file: contacts-index-logstash.conf
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "pswd"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/latest/mysql-connector-java-jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from contacts where updatedAt > :sql_last_value"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => http
        index => "contacts"
        document_type => "contact"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        host => "ES_NODE_HOST"
    }
}
# "* * * * *" -> run every minute
# sql_last_value is a built in parameter whose value is set to Thursday, 1 January 1970,
# or 0 if use_column_value is true and tracking_column is set
```

You can download the mysql jar from maven [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.5/mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar).

In case indexes do not exist in ES when this script is executed, they will be created automatically. Just like a normal post call to elasticsearch

Comment: This answer should be the preferred one.

Comment: Where is `contacts-index-logstash.conf` supposed to be located?

Comment: hi, @NikhilSahu how to test this configuration is run well?

Comment: you can have a new single row in database and no indexes/documents in ES. post running the script (if there are no errors), there should be a single document inside the specified index.

Comment: For a production case, you should have this script running as a daemon/service.

Comment: As of ES 7+, seems should use `logstash-integration-jdbc` plugin instead.

Comment: Is there a way to populate a doc field with array values?

Answer (score 46):

Finally i was able to find the answer. sharing my findings.

To use ElasticSearch with Mysql you will require The Java Database Connection (**JDBC**) importer. with JDBC drivers you can sync your mysql data into elasticsearch.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and you will require to install Java8 to run elasticsearch as it is written in Java

following are steps to install **ElasticSearch 2.2.0 and ElasticSearch-jdbc 2.2.0** and please note ***both the versions has to be same***

after installing Java8 ..... install elasticsearch 2.2.0 as follows

```
# cd /opt

# wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/deb/elasticsearch/2.2.0/elasticsearch-2.2.0.deb

# sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-2.2.0.deb
```

This installation procedure will install Elasticsearch in /usr/share/elasticsearch/ whose configuration files will be placed in /etc/elasticsearch .

Now lets do some basic configuration in config file. here  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml  is our config file
you can open file to change by

```
nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

and change cluster name and node name

For example :

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
 cluster.name: servercluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
 node.name: vps.server.com
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
```

Now save the file and start elasticsearch

```
 /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

to test ES installed or not run following

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

If you get following then your elasticsearch is installed now :)

```
{
  "name" : "vps.server.com",
  "cluster_name" : "servercluster",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.2.0",
    "build_hash" : "8ff36d139e16f8720f2947ef62c8167a888992fe",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-01-27T13:32:39Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now let's install **elasticsearch-JDBC**

download it from [`http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/importer/elasticsearch-jdbc/2.3.3.1/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.3.1-dist.zip`](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#quick-links) and extract the same in /etc/elasticsearch/ and create "logs" folder also there ( path of logs should be /etc/elasticsearch/logs)

I have one database created in mysql having name "**ElasticSearchDatabase**" and inside that **table named "test"** with fields id,name and email

```
cd /etc/elasticsearch
```

and run following

```
echo '{
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc":{

"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElasticSearchDatabase",
"user":"root",
"password":"",
"sql":"SELECT id as _id, id, name,email FROM test",
"index":"users",
"type":"users",
"autocommit":"true",
"metrics": {
            "enabled" : true
        },
        "elasticsearch" : {
             "cluster" : "servercluster",
             "host" : "localhost",
             "port" : 9300 
        } 
}
}' | java -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/lib/*" -"Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:////etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/bin/log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```

now check if mysql data imported in ES or not

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/users/_search/?pretty
```

If all goes well, you will be able to see all your mysql data in json format
and if any error is there you will be able to see them in /etc/elasticsearch/logs/jdbc.log file

**Caution :**

In older versions of ES ... plugin ***Elasticsearch-river-jdbc*** was used which is completely deprecated in latest version so do not use it.

I hope i could save your time :)

Any further thoughts are appreciated

Reference url : https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc

Comment: hi its not working for me "type" : "index_not_found_exception" and status 404. not connecting with mysql

Comment: Note: You need to have java 8 oracle installed: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
`. I had 9 openjdb installed and it was causing me access control errors.

Comment: @Yaxita...did you get a chance to find out, if you want to process rows read from mysql and then feed into elasticsearch.   and how did you handle incremntal changes in mysql (other than update timestamp) ??

Comment: I  have installed es-5.5.2 but there is no corresponding elasticsearch-jdbc 5.5.2 on http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/importer/elasticsearch-jdbc/

Comment: found error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"users","index":"users"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"users","index":"users"},"status":404}
Please help me How to resolve it.

Comment: `"port" : 9300 ` ??

Answer (score 6):

The logstash JDBC plugin will do the job:

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "factweavers"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/comp/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    schedule => "* * * *"
    statement => "SELECT" * FROM testtable where Date > :sql_last_value order by Date"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => Date
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "test-migrate"
  "document_type" => "data"
  "document_id" => "%{personid}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it more simple I have created a PHP class to Setup [MySQL with Elasticsearch](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-elasticsearch-with-mysql/). Using my Class you can sync your MySQL data in elasticsearch and also perform full-text search. You just need to set your SQL query and class will do the rest for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, your post doesn't answer the question. You referred about how to use elasticsearch with a kind of php API, but not how elasticsearch connects to the database language agnostic. What if one won't ever use PHP?
Your blogpost is also misleading. I'm not trying to offend you, but to express my scepticism.

Comment: I've already tried, but getting errors Fatal error: Can only throw objects in /Connection.php on line 539. Can you please help

Comment: @Ahmed is there a way to improve processing speed ? My OP is redirected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845773/how-to-process-large-data-from-database-using-php