# Elasticsearch:MySQL Error index_not_found_exception

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, centos7

My objective is to extract data from MySQL database using elasticsearch on Centos7.

I followed this link:[ElasticSearch how to integrate with Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152152/elasticsearch-how-to-integrate-with-mysql).

- Database named ElasticSearchDatabase created

  - "test" the table name
- Java 8 is installed.
- Elasticsearch 6.2.4 is installed.
- Elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1-dist.zip is unzipped under /etc/elasticsearch
- "logs" folder is created under /etc/elasticsearch

I got this result when I have executing :

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'

```
{
  "name" : "vps.server.com",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ICqEEr1VQHK8mZ82x7J_YQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
```

Then I have putted :

```
echo '{                                               
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc":{

"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElasticSearchDatabase",
"user":"root",
"password":"root",
"sql":"SELECT id as _id, id, name,email FROM test",
"index":"users",
"type":"users",
"autocommit":"true",
"metrics": {
            "enabled" : true
        },
        "elasticsearch" : {
             "cluster" : "my-application",
             "host" : "localhost",
             "port" : 9300 
        } 
}
}' | java -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1/lib/*" - 
 "Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:////etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc- 
  2.3.4.1/bin/log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" 
 "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```

To get the result that I want I have executed this cmd:

> curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/users/_search/?pretty

This is the result that I have got:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "users",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "users"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "users",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "users"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

Any one have an idea about this error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you checked that the index has been created successfully?

Comment: Thank you for your question, yes it's about the index, so i checked about it and after that all worked fine for me , it's just about the configuration file.

Comment: first.. check your database's name is `ElasticSearchDatabase` and check also for database''s user and password. then check this path(`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1/lib/`) is really exist.