# Data is not Syncing with Elastic Search 6.5.1

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

Database Mysql

I have referred to these links:

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin
- [ElasticSearch how to integrate with Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152152/elasticsearch-how-to-integrate-with-mysql)

Config file

logstash-sample.conf

```
                # Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
                # Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

                                            jdbc {
                jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash-6.5.1/logstash-core/lib/jars/x-pack-sql-jdbc-6.5.1.jar"
                jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
                jdbc_user => "root"
                jdbc_password => ""
                statement => "SELECT * FROM persons"
                jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
                jdbc_page_size => "50000"
                }

                }

                output{
                elasticsearch { codec => json hosts => ["localhost:9200"] index => "persons" }
                stdout { codec => rubydebug }
                }
```

Database Name Test

Datable Table persons

Index   Persons

Logs

```
            C:\logstash-6.5.1\bin>logstash -f logstash-sample.conf
            Sending Logstash logs to C:/logstash-6.5.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
            [2018-11-30T18:10:52,868][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
            [2018-11-30T18:10:52,883][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.5.1"}
            [2018-11-30T18:10:53,550][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"C:/logstash-6.5.1/bin/logstash-sample.conf"}
            [2018-11-30T18:10:53,559][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
            [2018-11-30T18:10:53,894][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Request  GET

http://localhost:9200/persons/_search/?pretty

```
            {
                "error": {
                    "root_cause": [
                        {
                            "type": "index_not_found_exception",
                            "reason": "no such index",
                            "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
                            "resource.id": "persons",
                            "index_uuid": "_na_",
                            "index": "persons"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
                    "reason": "no such index",
                    "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
                    "resource.id": "persons",
                    "index_uuid": "_na_",
                    "index": "persons"
                },
                "status": 404
            }
```

Any suggestion is most welcome

Comment: The problem comes from `No config files found in path: C:/logstash-6.5.1/bin/logstash-sample.conf` Where did you specify this path? in `logstash.yml` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply i did save path C:\logstash-6.5.1\config\logstash.yml

Comment: Please show your logstash.yml file

Comment: please use http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55258454618782156389

Comment: ok it seems you've not modified anything in there right? where is your `logstash-sample.conf` located? and which command do you use to run logstash?

Comment: pipeline.yml path  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03460491555222688005

Comment: logstash-sample.config  path C:\logstash-6.5.1\config\logstash-sample.config im new in elastic please bear with me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok since you're located in the `logstash/bin` folder and your `logstash-sample.conf` fiel is located in the `logstash/config` folder, you need to run logstash like this:

```
C:\logstash-6.5.1\bin> logstash -f ../config/logstash-sample.conf
                                        ^
                                        |
                               add this relative path
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help logstash-sample.conf  logs  LOgs http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=54725932227565245733 still i was not able see json data from db and index "persons" .

Comment: update file name http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07944564826348286325  with logstash-sample.logs

Comment: That's looking much better, though, no more missing config error

Comment: Add `--debug` when running logstash and show the new logs, please

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00170330724389692854  file name  logstash-sample_1.logs   Thanks

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07555255504900658615  C:\logstash-6.5.1\logs\logstash-plain.log

Comment: Weird that there's absolutely nothing being logged by the `jdbc` input

Comment: I see that a closing }  is missing at the end of your config file, but that's probably a copy/paste issue

Comment: Can you run this `curl -XGET http://localhost:9600/_node/stats?pretty` and share the output you get?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=44671467684815196066

Comment: ok, Logstash tells us that your config file has a `beats` input and an `elasticsearch` output, but no `jdbc` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks val for reply can you please help what i have done wrong ..thanks.

Comment: It's weird... are you sure you're running the correct configuration file? The one that runs is one that has the `beats` input, but not the `jdbc` input... Do you have several configuration files maybe, and picking the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked

windows

1. wrong Jdbc path.
2. mysql driver issue.

Config

```
                        jdbc {
                        jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash-6.5.1/logstash-core/lib/jars/x-pack-sql-jdbc-6.5.1.jar"
                        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
                        jdbc_user => "root"
                        jdbc_password => ""
                        statement => "SELECT * FROM persons"
                        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
                        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
                        }

                        }

                        output{
                        elasticsearch { codec => json hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200:9200"] index => "persons" }
                        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
                        }
```

Hope it help others.