# How to correctly implement elasticsearch on top of sql db datasource

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two sql databases, one database is often updated, whereas the second one is updated seldom.
I want my elasticsearch mechanism to work on top of these two databases.

How is it better to implement it?

ps. Im new to elastic search

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747698/5095957

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as final, because it's comment

Comment: I think it makes sense to mark this question a duplicate, since there is already an answer. Glad that you found something useful!