# Is there a way to keep Elasticsearch updated with SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, sql-server-2012, elastic-stack

Is there a way to create a trigger in SQL Server, or poll it for deletes?

Logstash and JDBC have been implemented, and there are already options for updating and inserting... but it seems delete is not an option.

If there is any way to do this, please leave suggestions.

Comment: these answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410920/elasticsearch-usage-with-mysql/40415430#40415430

Comment: Good links. Neither have a solid answer though; however they are helpful, thank you.

Comment: By "solid" you mean "ready baked" answer with a full solution that you can copy/paste?

Comment: The first link has been implemented, and ran into the same problem; no delete option.
The second option suggested using ES as append only, which does not help.
It seems the 'how to delete' may be the real question I'm asking here.

Comment: Ok, that's good. Now you can update your question and explain what you did and what did not work. The last two tools mentioned in the first link handle deletes.

Comment: Appreciate the help; it is a much narrower question now.

Comment: Still, I think it's worth it, because people with the same problem as you will be able to benefit from your experience with this.